# How to set active class in react render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

Using UI Kit

```js
   <ul className='uk-nav'>
          {languages.map(function (lang) {
            return (
              <li
                style={lang === this.state.selectedLanguage ? {color: '#d0021b'} : null}
                onClick={this.updateLanguage.bind(null, lang)}
                key={lang}>
                  {lang}
              </li>
            )
          }, this)}
        </ul>
```

I was able to get the output to render add the style  with the new color on click

How can i add css class name on this state

```
      className={lang === this.state.selectedLanguage ? {'uk-active'} : null}
```

How do you pass a classname with a condition.. in the same manner as style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `className` is just a string. Try this:

```js
 <ul className='uk-nav'>
          {languages.map(function (lang) {
            return (
              <li
                className={lang === this.state.selectedLanguage ? 'uk-active' : null}
                onClick={this.updateLanguage.bind(null, lang)}
                key={lang}>
                  {lang}
              </li>
            )
          }, this)}
        </ul>
```

Comment: No the style one works, I am asking about adding a className of `uk-active` instead of how i am doing it

Comment: perfect you are the best

Comment: @ZenaMesfin If my answer is the solution to your question, please click the gray checkmark on the left to make it green :)

Comment: i will in 6 minutes - apparently waiting period after edit